# How to print a nested list including the list name in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

I want to print out the contents of a nested list structure.

Here is my nested list:

```
usa = ['New York', 'Chicago', 'Seattle']
canada = ['Vancouver', 'Toronto', 'Kelowna']
england = ['London', 'Liverpool', 'Birmingham']

countries = [usa, canada, england]
```

I want the output to look like:

usa: New york, Chicago, Seattle, 
canada: Vancouver, Toronto, Kelowna, 
england: London, Liverpool, Birmingham,

Comment: You'll have to do some pretty 'hacky' things to print the variable's name, could you hard code the name into the structure?

Comment: Use a dictionary here, where the dictionary keys are the list names, and they map to the lists. Then you can just iterate using the dictionary's `items` method.

Answer (score 0):

heres a cool simle way to do that:

```
usa = ['New York', 'Chicago', 'Seattle']
canada = ['Vancouver', 'Toronto', 'Kelowna']
england = ['London', 'Liverpool', 'Birmingham']

print("usa: ", *usa)
print("canda: ", *canada)
print("england: ", *england)

#or if you want commas

print("usa: ", ", ".join(usa))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `dictionary`:

```
usa = ['New York', 'Chicago', 'Seattle']
canada = ['Vancouver', 'Toronto', 'Kelowna']
england = ['London', 'Liverpool', 'Birmingham']

dictionary = {'usa':usa,
              'canada':canada,
              'england':england}

for key in dictionary.keys():
    string = ', '.join(dictionary[key])
    print(f"{key}: {string}")
```

Output:

```
usa: New York, Chicago, Seattle
canada: Vancouver, Toronto, Kelowna
england: London, Liverpool, Birmingham
```